# Question on a property related to cyclotomic fields and thaine's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am reading the part of Washington's book related to Thaine's theorem. Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $F$ be the maximal real subfield of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$, i.e. $F=\mathbb Q(\zeta_m+\zeta_m^{-1})$. Moreover let $l$ be a prime congruent to $1$ modulo $m$.

> Then Washington defines an element $\epsilon=\prod_\gamma\prod_a(\zeta_m^{a\gamma}-\zeta_l)^{b_a}$ where $\gamma$ runs through $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{ml}|F(\zeta_l))$. He says that since $(m,l)=1$ each factor is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{ml}]$ and so $\epsilon$ is a unit of $F(\zeta_l)$. Why is this true?

I agree that each factor is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{ml}]$ but I cannot see how this implies that $\epsilon$ is a unit in $F(\zeta_l)$. Is there a more general property ? Please help, honestly I do not see even the logic in this claim. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's $b_a$ in the definition of $\epsilon$?

Comment: He only says that they are in $\mathbb Z$. You can put all of them equal to $1$ if you want, no problem for me.

Comment: By being a unit in $F(\zeta_l)$, you mean a unit in its ring of integers right? (since $F(\zeta_l)$ itself is a field and units are all the nonzero elements)

Comment: Yes of course! I find this notation as a standard one in this contexts. Thank you for trying to help me ! I really appreciate that, I have no ideas for this argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each factor is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{ml}]$, so is $\epsilon$. So let $\epsilon' \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{ml}]$ be such that $\epsilon \epsilon' = 1$. Let $G = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{ml})/F(\zeta_l))$. Let $\epsilon_1 = \prod_a (\zeta_m^{a}-\zeta_l)^{b_a}$. The conjugates of $\epsilon_1$ under the action of $G$ are precisely the $\prod_a (\zeta_m^{a\gamma}-\zeta_l)^{b_a}$'s where $\gamma$ ranges over elements in $G$, so $\epsilon$ is invariant under $G$-action. Therefore $\epsilon'$ is also invariant under $G$-action, so $\epsilon' \in F(\zeta_l) \cap \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{ml}]$, and this intersection is the ring of integers of $F(\zeta_l)$.

Comment: $\epsilon'$ being $G$-invariant means it's in $F(\zeta_l)$ (this is just Galois theory :)) and we started taking $\epsilon'$ to be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{ml}]$, therefore it's in the intersection.

Comment: Yes sorry I realized it in the same moment I wrote the comment !